# Lucene Get Highest Frequency Terms and Origin Document

Tags: java, lucene

I have implemented a word cloud through Lucene 4.0.0 calling the method getHighFreqTerms() as follows

```
TermStats[] termStats = HighFreqTerms.getHighFreqTerms(ir, HITS, "content");
```

I am trying to find a way to get the origin of each term. 
Is this possible? What do I need to do?
I thought of a solution which is to get a frequency value per term per document while at the same time storing in a HashMap the term and as a value an ArrayList with each of the documents, but I firmly believe this is inefficient.

Have you got any suggestions?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Don't you really want to use an IndexSearcher to get documents?

Comment: I really don't know..Do you think this is the best solution? I am thinking about the slow response I am going to get if I follow this approach.

Answer (score 0):

HighFreqTerms only gives you information about the index. If you want documents you have to use a query.

Comment: I need the highest frequency terms alongside with the origin document of each term, without parsing all documents. Is it possible with one call? Or with even using a second call but without having to loop over all documents? Thank you @Nicholas Karl .

Comment: Sure. Open this page with your browser, look over to the right hand side under the related column. There, you will find several 'related' questions. Many will have answers. Some will have more than one answer. Pick the ones that seem like they will answer your question the best. This may be difficult because there will probably be several very close, if not exact, matches. Browse through the top two or three closest matches. Try some of the answers out. Write some code, work at it for a few days. If you are still stuck, post what YOU HAVE TRIED ON YOUR OWN, and maybe someone will assist you.

Comment: It's better you should not bet that I haven't written any code. First of all, I have already implemented a typical search engine following the approach of looping over the documents. As a second attempt I have created a word cloud over a collection of documents following the approach of HighFreqTermms. For my third attempt, it is obvious that I am struggling and looking for some help. Why is that so bad, I do not understand.. Anyway, thank you for your time.